# How to set a color profile with exiftool?

Tags: linux, jpeg, color-profile, exiftool

I have some `.jpg` files without a color profile, and would like to set them to a particular color profile using `exiftool`.

what parameter do I need to supply to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `exiftool` to add a color profile, you need a `profile.file`

You can extract this from any `JPEG` image by:

```
exiftool -icc_profile -b somefile.jpg > profile.icc
```

Then attach this profile by using

```
exiftool "-icc_profile<=profile.icc" yourfile.jpg
```

Comment: An alternative to extract the profile is `exiftool -icc_profile -b -w icc somefile.jpg`: The command creates the ICC profile as `somefile.icc` automatically.